# Browser instantiating twice when using Selenium/Python/Nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose

I'm creating a sample test using Selenium and the python bindings and running it with nose.  I know I'm doing something wrong because the test opens two browsers (when setup is run, a Firefox window opens up and closes immediately, and then when the test runs driver.get, another window opens).  I have the following project:

```
/test_project
    /config
        config.ini
    /pages
        __init__.py
        test_page.py
    /test_scripts
        script.py
    __init__.py
    base.py
    config_parser.py
```

**config.ini:**

```
[Selenium]
browser: firefox
base_url: http://www.google.com/
chromedriver_path:
```

**base.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from config_parser import Config


class TestCase(object):

    def setup(self):
        self.config = Config()

        if self.config.read_config('Selenium', 'browser').lower() == 'firefox':
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        elif self.config.read_config('Selenium', 'browser').lower() == 'chrome':
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.config.read_config('Selenium', 'chromedriver_path'))

    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

**test_page.py**

```
from config_parser import Config

class TestPage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.config = Config()

    def open(self):
        self.driver.get(self.config.read_config('Selenium', 'base_url'))
        import time
        time.sleep(3)
```

**script.py**

```
from pages import test
from base import TestCase


class RandomTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        x = test.TestPage(self.driver)
        x.open()
        assert 1 == 1
```

Can someone help me understand why two browser windows are opening and what I can do to correct this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your base `TestCase` class is being recognized by nose test runner as a test too.

Mark it with [`@nottest`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) decorator:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from config_parser import Config
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
class TestCase(object):
    ...
```